# Laravel 9 auth | Change CSS of the default mails

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-9, laravel-authentication

I am using laravel auth for login, registration and password reset.

It has generated all views and I have customized everything and it works.

Now I want to customize the email templates, but I have no clue where they are and what the best practise is to do it.

They are not in `resources/views/vendor` ... .I do not have the vendor folder inside `resources/views`. I only have the sites there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

now u have resources/views/vendor/mail

css is inside themes folder called default.css

i think u can figure it out from there. Basically its just blade components